# Make image save with CSS hue effects applied

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some simple code that animates an image/gif to make it look like a rainbow. However, it obviously doesn't save the image like that if you download it, it saves the original gif. Heres an example of what I mean:

```css
.huerotate {
  animation: rainbow 2.5s linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes rainbow {
 from {
    -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(0deg);
      filter:hue-rotate(0deg);
    }
  to {
    -webkit-filter:hue-rotate(360deg);
      filter:hue-rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
 <img class="huerotate" src="https://emoji.gg/assets/emoji/7274_crabrave.gif">
```

When you right click it and download it, it's the original, taken [here](https://emoji.gg/assets/emoji/7274_crabrave.gif). Is their any way to make it save with the hue effects?

Comment: use a screen record

Comment: @TemaniAfif Hi, thanks for commenting. I do not want to use a screen record for a couple of reasons, one being that it doesn't preserve the transparency of the background. I would like to do this programmably. Thanks